# Disable NTFS Compression, but only for new files

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, compression

I have an external NTFS drive which I enabled compression on a few days ago. I thought it would help save disk space, but only saved about 1% overall. Now disk writes seem much slower and the performance on it is worse. I imagine this is because each new file is being written compressed.

I would like to disable compression for all new files on the drive, but I would like to leave alone all files which have already been compressed. Uncompressing all files on the drive might take several days, due to the amount of data on the drive. So I want to avoid doing this if possible.

Can I simply remove the compression attribute from all folders in the filesystem, but leave the already-compressed files untouched? I'm not sure if this is possible, and the `Properties` window in the File Explorer interface only allows me to disable compression in the root folder, or in all subfolders and files. I only want to disable it for *new* files, not *all* files.

Example:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not sure if running `attrib -C E: /D` from an elevated command prompt might do the trick, but I suspect `compact /u E:` will operate on all files... http://www.windowscommandline.com/tag/ntfs-compression/ perhaps not using the `/s` (recursive) option will actually be what you want.

Comment: @Mokubai I tried both of those commands. The first one said: `Invalid switch - -C`. The second command said: `Setting the directory E:\ not to compress new files [OK]         1 files within 1 directories were uncompressed.` It seems that neither command was effective in doing what you said. Could you offer any suggestions?

Comment: @Mokubai I figured out a way to solve the problem based on that command you gave me. See my answer for more details. Apparently I can only accept it in 7 hours, though.

Comment: That's awesome, glad that you found a workable solution. Sadly I was a bit at a loss after your comment as it sounded like `compact` would do the opposite of what you wanted. It good that you found a way to make it only work on directories.

Comment: @Mokubai Sure, I understand. Thanks again for helping me reach the solution – wouldn't have figured it out without your initial advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to use Cygwin. I realized that in Cygwin, I can use the Unix `find` command to operate on all directories in the filesystem and execute Windows commands on those folders. Cygwin's `find` has the unique capability to use Unix or Windows commands in the `-exec` parameter. This does not work on WSL, as far as I know. From my own testing, it seems WSL only runs Unix commands.

So my command was:

```
find /cygdrive/e -type d -exec compact /u {} \;
```

And this actually worked. It "uncompressed" each folder, but left all files intact (compressed). No files were actually uncompressed, although the `Compressed` attribute was removed from each folder in the filesystem. So now all new files will be written without compression, but all the old files which were already compressed will stay compressed until I decide to decompress them someday. But it saved me from doing a lot of extra writes on my disk for the time being.

Credit to [@Mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai) for telling me about the `compact` Windows command, which gave me the idea to feed that command to the `-exec` flag in `find`.